# Understanding of Tkinter Window geometry

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, geometry, window

to create a fullscreen window in Python through Tkinter i do this:

```
w, h = window.winfo_screenwidth(), window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
```

And it works, of course.
But I'd like to know why it is like this.
Why am I typing "%dx%d+0+0"? What does Python read in that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w, h = window.winfo_screenwidth(), window.winfo_screenheight()`

`w`, and `h` are now holding the value of the screen height and width, say `1280`, and `920`

`window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))`

Then it is a straightforward python string formatting (the old fashion way):

`window.geometry("1280x920+0+0")`

which is a string that tkinter can parse. (welcome to the 1990'es)

Comment: Oh thanks, so the "d"s are basically holding w and h

Comment: You are welcome; yes, you get the idea. When you have half an hour, this is worth reading through: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html